# VS Code: [Python (analysis)] unknown variable 'True'

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am asking just out of curiosity. Everything works as intended but apparently VS Code thinks the True variable does not exist:
[image: screenshot]

Also I get error messages from pylint when I import classes from pylab:

[image: screenshot]

This is strange and a bit annoying. Has anyone else experienced this behavior?

Thank you.

---

EDIT. I was asked to commit the errors in text form.

> `[Python (analysis)] unknown variable 'True'`
>
> This error occurs everytime I use the boolean True. I see the same behavior when I use False.

and

> `[pylint] E0611:No name 'X' in module 'pylab'`
>
> This error occurs everytime I try to import `X` from pylab with `from pylab import X` where `X` stands for example for `array` or `arange`.

Comment: Copy and paste the code and error as text, not screenshots

Comment: Hever you tried using true?  all lowercase letters.. Just a thought.

Comment: lowercase true is not an intrinsic python boolean value. I also get this error, when I just type `a = True`. 

`a = true` gives `name 'true' is not defined`

Comment: What Extensions do you have installed? What if you deactivate everything except the standard microsoft python extension?

Comment: I deactivated Jupyter and Code Runner as you suggested. This did not solve the issue.

Comment: Very weird; I just tried a fresh install of VS Code with only Microsofts Python Extensions and I received no error with `True`

Comment: I removed and reinstalled the Python extension and the error persists. Maybe I just have to reinstall VS Code. But since I am working on a project atm I can't do it right now..

Comment: Why is this question down voted?  It's a valid question and I am having the same issue with vs code reporting `[Python (analysis)] unknown variable 'True'`

Answer (score 0):

Check may be you typing some symbols of "True" not in latin locale, eg symbol  "е" (not latin "e") present in Cyrillic locale, but it has other code unlike in latin locale. And it can be cause of this error.

Comment: I don't think so.. Other editors like sublimetext show no errors and the code runs as intended. I think there is something wrong with VS Code or possibly pylint. I will try to reinstall everything from scratch tomorrow. Thank you!

Comment: With interpreted languages it can be. The code will not produce errors until the branch reaches the specified place in runtime. And then the program will stop with an error. In order to prevent this and need programs linters.

Comment: Code like this will working good, until b not equal 1:
b = 2
if b == 1:
    b = TruеTrue